# using ngIf with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Hi i am trying to use two types of ng-repeat statements based on the codition using ng-if. Somehow it is not working.
Code:

```
<div ng-if="orderby === '0'">
                <div  ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="orderby === '1'">
                <div  ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search| orderBy:'-timestamp'"></div>
            </div>
```

I have two controller, they are using the same template. In one template i set the value of `$scope.orderby = '0'` .  In this template i want to use `ng-repeat` without `orderBy` and vice versa.
This isn't working out. Is there other way of doing this type of functionality?

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific than "it is not working", as this will help answerers better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create object : `someObjectName.orderby` instead of primitive variable  `orderby`.
And your binding will be:

```
<div ng-if="someObjectName.orderby === '0'">
                <div  ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="someObjectName.orderby === '1'">
                <div  ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search| orderBy:'-timestamp'"></div>
            </div>
```

`ng-repeat` have another scope and your `orderby` variable out of `ng-repeat` is not same in `orderby` inside `ng-repeat` scope.

Read this article for more information about scopes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes